# Can an object's resonance be changed (and how easily if possible)?

Tags: resonance

If I take a ruler and restrict the motion of a part of the ruler, would that change the resonant frequency of the ruler? I was wondering this because if I take a ruler and have half of it off a desk and then flick the ruler down to make it vibrate, the note it releases will be different than if only a fourth of the ruler were off the desk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the basis of many musical instruments. Guitar strings, for example, make different notes depending on where your fingers are on the fretboard. Flutes make different notes according to which holes your fingers cover up.

And, it's not just sound. You "tune in" a radio station by adjusting resonators in the radio.

Comment: I didn't even know that changing resonance was used so often! But if you could explain how the resonators in a radio change frequency, for example, that would be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that we are talking only about physical vibration of an object, and I'll ignore electronics, atomic vibrations, etc.

There are many factors that affect the resonant frequency. You've discovered one: the length of the object. That principle is used in violins and guitars: Pressing down on the string at different locations changes the effective length of the string, which changes the frequency.

Another factor is tension. This is used to tune violins: turning the tuning pegs or the fine-tuning screws changes the frequency by altering the tension.

Next there is mass: a more massive object will vibrate at a lower frequency. The double bass has thicker (and longer) strings than a violin, giving it a lower pitch. Gluing a weight on your ruler will lower its vibration frequency.

Stiffness also affects the resonant frequency: the stiffer the object, the higher the frequency.

Lastly, here are some other factors that affect the frequency. They have smaller effects, and are harder to control than the ones above: temperature, air density (and composition), air pressure.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful, but now I have a followup question. Is there a formula that brings together all of these factors to allow somebody to calculate the resonant frequency of an object without having to test for it manually?

Comment: Here's the formula for the resonant frequency of a string: https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Resonant+frequency+of+string